# How to More Efficiently Pivot Semi Colon Separated Columns into a 0/1/2 Indicator Matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, lambda, pivot

I am starting with a pandas Dataframe that is generated by the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'basket_1':['apple;banana;orange', 'apple;banana;mango', 'mango;orange;grapefruit'],
        'basket_2':['pineapple;strawberry;peach', 'peach;lemon;guava', 'strawberry;peach;guava']}
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


                  basket_1                    basket_2
0      apple;banana;orange  pineapple;strawberry;peach
1       apple;banana;mango           peach;lemon;guava
2  mango;orange;grapefruit      strawberry;peach;guava
```

I also start with a numpy array of all of the fruits present in either basket column (as well as some additional fruits), generated as follows for the purpose of this example:

```
import numpy as np

fruits = np.array(['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango', 'grapefruit', 'kiwi', 'pineapple', 
                   'strawberry', 'peach', 'lemon', 'guava', 'lime'])
```

From this initial Dataframe and array, I am looking to generate the resulting Dataframe in the most efficient way possible:

[Final Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51wUY.png)

```
                  basket_1                    basket_2  apple  banana  orange  mango  grapefruit  kiwi  pineapple  strawberry  peach  lemon  guava  lime
0      apple;banana;orange  pineapple;strawberry;peach      1       1       1      0           0     0          2           2      2      0      0     0
1       apple;banana;mango           peach;lemon;guava      1       1       0      1           0     0          0           0      2      2      2     0
2  mango;orange;grapefruit      strawberry;peach;guava      0       0       1      1           1     0          0           2      2      0      2     0
```

The final result has added a column for each of the elements present in the fruits array along with a '1' in a given row if the given fruit is present in the 'basket_1' column, a '2' in a given row if the given fruit is present in the 'basket_2' column, and a '0' otherwise.

At the moment, I am using the following code to transform the initial Dataframe into the desired format:

```
def whichBasket(b1, b2, fruit):
    if fruit in b1:
        val = 1
    elif fruit in b2:
        val = 2
    else:
        val = 0
    return val

for f in fruits:
    df[f] = df.apply(lambda x: whichBasket(x.basket_1, x.basket_2, f), 1)
```

This solution calls an apply function iterating through each row of the Dataframe nested inside a for-loop iterating through each fruit, which works fine for a small example such as this one. However, I am attempting to scale this up to a Dataframe with over 1000 fruits and over 80000 rows, and this solution is far too slow to complete this job in a reasonable amount of time.

Any ideas for ways to improve this code's performance in terms of shortening running time? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option,

1. create dataframe by appending all the columns from fruits list to current df
2. User `str.get_dummies` to generate dummy columns and assign to original df
3. For basket 2, add 1 to ensure str.get_dummies returns 2 as value instead of 1
4. Replace nan in missing cells with 0

   ```
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(columns = fruits)], axis = 1)

    df = df.assign(**df['basket_1'].str.get_dummies(';'))

    df = df.assign(**df['basket_2'].str.get_dummies(';') * 2)

    df = df.fillna(0)
   ```

Edit: addressing @Matt's question on a fruit being present in either basket but not at the same time.
Slightly different approach, concat df with get_dummies results from baskets 1 & 2. Use reindex to include rest of the columns from fruits list.

```
data = {'basket_1':['apple;banana;orange', 'apple;banana;mango', 'mango;orange;grapefruit','mango;peach;grapefruit'],
        'basket_2':['pineapple;strawberry;peach', 'peach;lemon;guava', 'strawberry;peach;guava', 'apple;lemon;guava']}
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fruits = np.array(['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango', 'grapefruit', 'kiwi', 'pineapple', 
                   'strawberry', 'peach', 'lemon', 'guava', 'lime'])
req_cols = df.columns.tolist() + fruits.tolist()

df = pd.concat([df, df['basket_1'].str.get_dummies(';'), df['basket_2'].str.get_dummies(';')*2], axis = 1).groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
df = df.reindex(req_cols, axis = 1, fill_value = 0)
```

Comment: @Vasishali this is really fast compared to what i'm about post, and much faster than OPs solution, but when you perform the line on basket_2, the final dataframe isn't correct.

Comment: the +1 should change to *2 and then the answer is correct. This is a great solution. On  a 90000 row df it takes 1 second; OPs took 20 seconds on my laptop.

Comment: @Jonathan Leon, My bad and you are right! It should be *2. Thank you for pointing out, corrected the answer

Comment: @Vaishali Thanks for providing this solution! Quick follow up: Do you have any thoughts for maintaining this level of efficiency if it is possible for a fruit to be in either basket 1 or 2, but not at the same time (i.e. apple is in basket 1 in row 1, but is in basket 2 in row 3)? Currently, this solution works only if each fruit can only be in one of the two baskets (i.e. apple can only be in basket 1)

Comment: @Vaishali Thank you for providing the update!

Answer (score 1):

You can perform:

1. Get `basket_1` entries with `str.split()` and then create columns with `pd.Series()`
2. Similarly, for `basket_2`
3. Concat `df` with the 2 sets of newly created columns from the 2 baskets
4. Reindex new columns with list of `fruits` and `fillna()` with 0 for non-defined entries.

```
df_b1 = df['basket_1'].str.split(';').apply(lambda x: pd.Series([1] * len(x), index=x))
df_b2 = df['basket_2'].str.split(';').apply(lambda x: pd.Series([2] * len(x), index=x))
df1 = pd.concat([df, df_b1, df_b2],  axis=1)
df1 = df1.set_index(['basket_1', 'basket_2']).reindex(columns=fruits).fillna(0, downcast='infer').reset_index()
```

Result:

```
print(df1)


                  basket_1                    basket_2  apple  banana  orange  mango  grapefruit  kiwi  pineapple  strawberry  peach  lemon  guava  lime
0      apple;banana;orange  pineapple;strawberry;peach      1       1       1      0           0     0          2           2      2      0      0     0
1       apple;banana;mango           peach;lemon;guava      1       1       0      1           0     0          0           0      2      2      2     0
2  mango;orange;grapefruit      strawberry;peach;guava      0       0       1      1           1     0          0           2      2      0      2     0
```